# JBoss 7.1 cannot deploy .aar file (Axis2) integrated with Spring

Tags: jboss, apache-axis

I have used eclipse to create an Axis2 Web Service packaged as .aar file as described here:

Axis2 Integration with the Spring Framework
http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/spring.html#a26

*The project for the WS was created with Maven.

Then, I upload the service using the Axis2 Web Admin Module.

However, I get

**Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/axis2/extensions/spring/receivers/ApplicationContextHolder**

If I package my web service as .war it is deployed correctly from Eclipse.

**What could be done?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best example I found:

http://fazlansabar.blogspot.com.es/2012/04/apache-axis2-tutorial-integrating-with.html

Now I got it deployed from the Axis2 Web Admin console.

The trick was to copy the spring jars inside WEB-INF/lib of axis2.war.
Then, you have to order correctly the files and upload the .aar file from the console. The Web Services will appear in the "Available Services" list.

To keep permanetly the service, copy the .aar to **WEB-INF\services\** inside axis2.war as described in:

http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/adv-userguide.html